# Using alternative of Library loaded by Java Bootstrap class loader

Tags: java, classpath

I need use the both jars local_policy.jar and US_export_policy.jar with unlimited key size strength. The JRE comes bundled with versions of the jars, with limited key size strength. But I can't replace the original jars in the $JAVA_HOME/lib/security (insufficient rights), so i need them to override (at runtime?) somehow.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It would appear that you can override the bootstrap classpath with the `-Xbootclasspath` JVM argument. See the 'Non-standard options' section of [this page](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.3/docs/tooldocs/win32/java.html) for more info.

Comment: Good idea! I tried to use the flag -Xbootclasspath/p to prepend the two jars in the boot classpath. Unfortunately that seems not to work properly. The jars of the original JRE path /lib/security/*.jar will be used..
I can use the option -Xbootclasspath, but then I have to copy all lib's required for bootstrapping the vm to the specified path.